# DateTime causing application to crash on a physical phone?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am creating an app where the system checks for whether an event's start date is within one week of the current date.

Here is the code:

```
private void GetUpcomingEvents()
{
    CredentialsInit();

    var range = $"{upcomingEventsSheet}!A2:C"; 
    var request = service.Spreadsheets.Values.Get(SpreadsheetId, range);

    var response = request.Execute();
    var values = response.Values;

    // I am using Google Sheets API as well but it doesn't affect the code

    eventTitle.Clear();
    eventStartDate_.Clear();
    eventEndDate_.Clear();

    DateTime startDate = DateTime.Today;
    Console.WriteLine(startDate);
    DateTime endDate = startDate.AddDays(7);

    foreach (var row in values)
    {
        DateTime eventStartDate = DateTime.Parse(row[1].ToString());

        if (eventStartDate >= startDate && eventStartDate < endDate)
        {
            eventTitle.Add(row[0].ToString());
            eventStartDate_.Add(row[1].ToString());
            eventEndDate_.Add(row[2].ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

It is then called using

```
await Task.Run(() => GetUpcomingEvents());
```

The problem is, this code runs fine on an Android emulator (both in debug and release), but when launched on an android phone, the app immediately crashes on startup. Any idea why this happens?

Edit: As requested, this is where the error arises from

```
DateTime eventStartDate = DateTime.Parse(row[1].ToString());
```

Where `row[1].ToString() == "08/16/2021"`

Comment: Is there anything in the log?

Comment: @JonSkeet nope, everything works and builds just fine, even archiving works

Comment: I mean the log at execution time - where I'd expect to see any exceptions being logged.

Comment: @JonSkeet nope, nothing out of the ordinary

Comment: So have you tried anything to work out which line is causing the error? Are you able to use a debugger with a real phone? If you try removing almost all the code from your method, leaving just a bit of logging, what happens?

Comment: Maybe there are exceptions on your real phone. You can use `try{await Task.Run(() => GetUpcomingEvents());} catch { /* Give feedback */}`.

Comment: @Michael Since I am working in a group, we tried using each of our phones and the app crashes on every single one of our phones, so I don't think it's an exception

Comment: @JonSkeet The problem arises from `foreach(var row in values) { DateTime eventStartDate = DateTime.Parse(row[1].ToString());`

Comment: @UnidentifiedX: I think you may have misunderstood what "exception" means. If `row[1].ToString()` doesn't contain a valid date/time, that will throw an exception on every phone. Again: are you able to step through this in a debugger? If so, I'd expect that would show you the exception. It would also be useful to show the value of `row[1].ToString()` in the question - and reduce the code to an absolute *minimal* example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet Sorry for the ambiguity, but `row[1].ToString() == "08/16/2021"`, and I have run the application through a debugger, and no, no exceptions were thrown

Comment: Running it in a debugger *on the phone where it crashes*? That would very much surprise me. I would expect it to throw a `FormatException` on that line, if it's going to fail. (I suspect it succeeds in an emulator because that uses a US culture, but fails on a phone with a non-US culture.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Since I live outside of the US, I changed the time, region and language to where I live on the emulator and it still seems to work, but not on the physical phone

Edit: And yes, I ran it on an online debugger where it does crash, and no exceptions were thrown

Comment: Can you add a messagebox after `CredentialsInit();` to make sure this works on the actual device?

Comment: So you were able to step over that statement onto the next one, even on a device which crashes? If you put that code within a try/catch block and add logging in the catch block, does *that* show an exception at all? (I strongly suspect an exception *is* being thrown.)

Comment: @Luuk yup, it does work on the actual device

Comment: @JonSkeet put the code in a try-catch statement, with `catch(Exception e){await DisplayAlert("error", e.GetType().ToString(), "ok"); }`, and the thing is, nothing shows up

Comment: Rather than trying to display an alert when running in a task, I would strongly recommend relying on logging. Log before the `DateTime.Parse` call, after it, and in the catch block.

Comment: @JonSkeet how do I do that? I tried researching but nothing useful came up

Comment: `Console.WriteLine()` will write to the device log.  You need to use that or the interactive debugger to determine what the data is that is causing the crash.

Comment: @Jason yeah I did look at the device log, and there was nothing out of the ordinary

Comment: you need to use DateTime.ParseExact or DateTime.TryParse - more than likely the device is expecting "DD/MM" instead of "MM/DD" and is blowing up because "16" is not a valid month.  This should not be a difficult problem to solve.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't provided much of the information, but only this line could cause such a crash:

```
DateTime eventStartDate = DateTime.Parse(row[1].ToString());
```

This line is handled within the current `System.Globalization` current culture as you haven't provided the other as the second argument. As such the ability to execute properly this line depends on the current culture of the device/emulator, so on some it will work on some it won't.